# Grails 3 - check if command object values are all null

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.1

I have a class:

```
class PersonCommand implements Validateable {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
        firstName nullable: true
        lastName nullable: true
    }
}
```

I have a List of type PersonCommand that I need to validate. I would like to iterate through each element and check if both firstName and lastName are null. Is there a way to do this without explicitly checking for those properties? I would like to do something like:

```
for(PersonCommand person in people) {
    if(areAllMapValuesNull(person.properties)) {
        person.validate()
    } else {
        ...
```

but person.properties has other properties added to it than just firstName and lastName since it is Validateable. I'm not looking for help on the areAllMapValuesNull() function, only on getting the values firstName and lastName without hard-coding the checks.

Comment: try `person.properties.entrySet().findAll{ it.key in ["firstName", "lastName"]}` instead of `person.properties`

Comment: That unfortunately also has properties like class, errors, constraints, and constraintsMap.

Comment: After you do `findAll{ it.key in ["firstName", "lastName"]}` or in a generic way for all persistent properties only `findAll{ it.key in person.persistantProperties.name}`, it will not contain class, errors constraints etc properties..

Comment: There is no 'persistantProperties' property for the command object. I'm  using Grails 3, if that affects that API.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, i didn't test, is a draft to your possible solution, right.

```
  def p = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(PersonCommand.class)
  for(PersonCommand person in people) {
    def prop = person.properties.entrySet().findAll{ it.key in p.persistantProperties } 
    if(areAllMapValuesNull(prop)) {
        person.validate()
    } else {}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I get an exception: 'org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Identity property not found, but required in domain class'. My IDE is also telling me persistantProperties is deprecated.

Comment: What is your grails version ?
Is PersonCommand a DomainClass ?

Comment: Looking in the internet i saws too interfaces http://docs.grails.org/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClass.html#getPersistentProperties() and http://docs.grails.org/latest/api/grails/core/GrailsDomainClass.html and it seems to me that the only thing that changed was the package.

Comment: PersonCommand is not a domain class. It is a command object. I am using Grails 3. The domain class associated with the command object has some different fields, and so I would not want to refer to the domain class.